# How can i auto search from multiple column in my datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a textbox that shows the rows in the datagrid and the datagrid will only show the rows that is related to what i typed in.
I have a code here but it only search from the column "Title". What i want is it will search not only in column "Title" but also in column "Author" and "Name".
Here is what i got:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
       dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

Comment: Some examples: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then change your filter condition to include those condition as well like below

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' OR AUTHOR LIKE '%{0}%' OR Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' OR Author LIKE '%{0}%' OR Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR`

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' OR Author LIKE '%{0}%' OR Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text);
```

More information can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).